# Reference to an object from a callback function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have following situation. In a constructor of a pseudo class I attach a click event to an element. When the event is triggered I would like to refer from the callback function to the object where the event was set.

Code of the pseudo class constructor

```
function MyClass(){
  this.myClassAttribute = "A class attribute";

  // here `this` refers to the object

  $("span").click(function(){
    // here `this` refer to a matched element, i.e. "span"
    // How to get the value of `myClassAttribute`?
  });

}
```

How to refer to the object without an global variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Javascript an anonymous function is able to reference all variables that existed at the scope of the function's creation. Since `this` gets reassigned in the callback function, you can create a local variable to store it before you enter the callback.

```
function MyClass(){
  this.myClassAttribute = "A class attribute";
  var myClass = this;

  $("span").click(function(){
    myClass.myClassAttribute = "hello";
  });

}
```

Comment: Your click handler function is a closure, they are a powerful part of javascript http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+closures

Comment: I know this is already several years old. But I ran into a problem with this solution. If you have several class instances, better use the answer provided by @Stephen Delano. Because myClass will always contain the last instance that has been created.

Answer (score 8):

This is better documented in the jQuery API. [jQuery Bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind)

$.click is just a shortcut for $.bind('click', /*no data*/, callback)

```
$('span').bind('click', { parentObj: this }, function(e) {
  var parentObj = e.data.parentObj;
  // the rest of your code goes here
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using jQuery $get. The call back function passed is actually a class function so you don't have access to the specific instance data.

I suppose this is a limitation of Javascript languange that does not handle object function as a call back parameter.

I solved using a similar workaround:

```js
class customer {

    constructor() {
        this.customerName ="";
    }

    getCustomerName() {
        let dataRequest = {
            url: '/getCustomerName',
            data: {
                customerId: '035'
            },
            dataType: "json"
        };
        var thisObject = this;
        $.get(dataRequest).done(
            function(dbD) { thisObject.queryData(dbD,thisObject)}
        );
    }

    queryData(dbData,obj) {
        obj.customerName = dbData[0];
    }
}
```