# How to use JQuery callback functions with Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-callback

I have a Javascript object the following:

```
function extraFields(id) {
    this.numActiveFields = 0;

    ...

    this.addRow = function(quoteClass, rowClass) {
        var remButton = $("<span></span>")
        .addClass(rowClass)
        .addClass(quoteClass)
        .click(function() {
            //here I want to refer to the object's variable, but instead refer
            //to the JQuery object
            this.numActiveFields++;
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to change the object's variable from inside the callback function. How would I do that? Should I change the way I declare the object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference to an object from a callback function in jQuery.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579672/reference-to-an-object-from-a-callback-function-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the callback function "this" is the "remButton" you created. Just save "this" in a variable before the callback and then use that instead.

For a better explanation please look at the link that mplungjan suggested:
[Reference to an object from a callback function in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579672/reference-to-an-object-from-a-callback-function-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks, I was sure there was a thread like that, but couldn't find it.